# Эффект разбития страниц на группы

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

Вот то, чего я хочу достичь. У меня есть ViewPager. Нужно надпись сверху, которая меняется. когда переключаюсь с 2 на 3 страницы и обратно соответственно. Всего 2 группы, то есть всего 2 надписи, которые меняются только в этом моменте. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать, хотелось бы чтобы всё было аккуратно, если, к примеру, задержать палец между 2 и 3 страницей, то и надписи задержались бы на смене своих позиций, как я нарисовал на 3 части рисунка.